# Return Bitmap from Java Class to Activity

Tags: java, android, callback

I am using google ML kit for face detection and want to return the Bitmap object from CameraSource.java class to ImageViewerActivity, but it always return null

```
public Bitmap takePicture() {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            Log.i("ASDF", "Supported Picture: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
            list.add(size.height);
        }

        Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(closest(1080, list));
        Log.i("Width x Height", cs.width+"x"+cs.height);
        params.setPictureSize(cs.width, cs.height); //1920, 1080
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

                //if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
                if (facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                } else {
                    Matrix matrixMirrory = new Matrix();
                    float[] mirrory = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                    matrixMirrory.setValues(mirrory);
                    matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrory);
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                }
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            }
        });
return bitmap;
    }
```

I want this bitmap to load on a ImageView in other activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach which you can follow is passing callback to your method from the activity which is calling this function. Like in your case your should define a callback in ImageViewActivity and pass it down to this method.

```
Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallBack = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, final Camera camera) {

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            //if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
            if (facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            } else {
                Matrix matrixMirrory = new Matrix();
                float[] mirrory = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
                matrixMirrory.setValues(mirrory);
                matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrory);
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            }
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    }
```

And modify your takepicture method like

```
public Bitmap takePicture(Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallBack) {
    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Camera.Size size : params.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        Log.i("ASDF", "Supported Picture: " + size.width + "x" + size.height);
        list.add(size.height);
    }

    Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(closest(1080, list));
    Log.i("Width x Height", cs.width+"x"+cs.height);
    params.setPictureSize(cs.width, cs.height); //1920, 1080
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallBack);
}
```